# Bean Validation: How to localize messages programmatically?

Tags: java, validation, jakarta-ee, jax-rs, bean-validation

In my current rest-service scenario I need to be able to provide localized error messages to  individual clients.

Think of a method like `void validate(Locale locale)` which is called on the parameter object when receiving some request.

The locale information can be squeezed out of the http headers.

How can I instruct/configure a validator to use a certain language when violation messages are getting interpolated?

As far as I know a validator chooses the used Locale by calling `Locale.getDefault()`.

So far I couldn't find anything other than [this](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/12/jax-rs-bean-validation-error-message-internationalization.html?ModPagespeed=noscript) article which does not exactly fit to my needs (a story too long to tell).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

According to the [spec](http://beanvalidation.org/1.1/spec/) you have two possibilities:

Use [`interpolate(String, Context, Locale)`](http://beanvalidation.org/1.1/spec/#message-interpolation-default-locale) or
implement a [custom message interpolator](http://beanvalidation.org/1.1/spec/#custom-message-resolution).

> A custom message interpolator may be provided (e.g., to interpolate contextual data, or to **adjust the default Locale** used).

See also:

- [Example 5.10. Use MessageInterpolator to use a specific Locale value](http://beanvalidation.org/1.1/spec/#validationapi-message-examples-specificlocale)
- [Example 5.11. Contextual container possible MessageInterpolator implementation](http://beanvalidation.org/1.1/spec/#validationapi-message-examples-jsflocale)

Comment: Thank you! Especially the links you provided were useful. I didn't know the bv spec offered implementation examples for problems like this.